# The Normal Bundle of a level set is trivial

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, fiber-bundles

Let $M,N$ be manifolds and $f:N\to M$ an embedding.
For every $p\in N$, $df_p:T_pN\to T_pM$ shows that $T_pN\subset T_pM$.
For every $p\in N$, define the **normal space** of $N$ in $M$ at $p$ as 
$$
(\eta_{N|M})_p:=\frac{T_pM}{T_pN}.
$$
Gluing together all these spaces, we obtain
$$
\eta_{N|M}:=\frac{TM|_N}{TN}
$$
the **normal bundle** of $N$ in $M$.

The *Tubular Neighbourhood Theorem* holds.

> Let $S$,$M$ be manifolds without boundary, $i:S\to M$ an embedding.
>   Then there exists
>
> - $T$, neighborhood of $i(S)$ in $M$
> - $v:\eta_{S|M}\to T$ such that $i=v\circ s_0$, where $s_0:S\to \eta_{S|M}$ is the zero section.

Now, let $M$ be a manifold with our boundary, $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function, $y\in Reg(f)$ and $N$ be a connected component of $f^{-1}(y)$. I have to prove that $\eta_{N|M}$ is trivial.

I can't understand how to proceed. First of all because the definition of normal bundle is not clear to me at all.

Comment: Do you have some reference (book, online notes or else) for the normal bundle? I've always seen the normal bundle defined for an embedded submanifold of a Riemannian manifold, so it is interesting to see that it can be defined without a Riemannian metric.

Comment: In general, if $E\to F$ is an injective homomorphism of smooth vector bundles over $M$, then there exists a smooth vector bundle $G$ over $M$ along with a vector bundle homomorphism $F\to G$ such that $0\to E\to F\to G\to 0$ is short exact. Moreover, the pair $(G,F\to G)$ is unique up to unique isomorphism of smooth vector bundles. The vector bundle $G$ is then denoted $G=F/E$. This is how one constructs $TM|_N/TN$. These are all the interesting remarks I can come up with by myself. It would be interesting to see any further comments about $TM|_N/TN$ available in the literature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Showing that the normal bundle is trivial is the same thing as demonstrating a nonvanishing global section of $\eta$ (since it's one-dimensional). At each point $n \in N$ let $v \in (TM/TN)_n$ be the unique vector with $df(v) = 1 \in T_y \Bbb R$. (Why is there a unique such vector?) This is a continuous section of the normal bundle, as you can check in local coordinates (pick a slice chart for the submersion). Because this section cannot vanish anywhere (it maps to something nonzero!), this is the desired trivializing section.

Comment: Okay, but I still can't understand why such a vector in the normal space exists

Comment: @avati91 what's the definition of a regular value?

Comment: That is not a critical value. A critical value is the image of a critical point, i.e. $p\in M$ such that $rank df(p)$ is not maximum

Comment: @avati91: This isn't entirely correct, because it implies there can be non-critical points of a map $\Bbb R^{n-1} \to \Bbb R^n$, say. A critical point is one such that $\text{rank } Jf(p)$ is the dimension of the codomain (ie, such that $Jf(p)$ is surjective). In any case, you know every $p \in N$ is a regular point. What does that tell you?

Comment: that $df_p$ has maximum rank for every $p\in N$

Comment: @avati91: So if $p\in N$ why is there a $v \in T_p N$ with $df_p(v) = 1$?

Comment: Because is surjective! But why is $v$ unique?

Comment: Otherwise the section it's not well-defined

Comment: @avati91: It's unique when you pass to the normal bundle. I've given you all the tools you need now.

Comment: Let $v_1,v_2\in (\eta_{N|M})_p$ such that $df_p(v_1)=df_p(v_2)=1$. I have to prove that $[v_1]=[v_2]$, i.e. there exists $w\in T_pN$ such that $v_1-v_2=w$. But I don't have ideas.